# Stop browser blobs from expiring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

want to create a react application that users upload images and instantly should be interacting with them. I'm not going to upload them into any server. I just want to use them in the user's browser.

For that currently use blobs. I save those blob URL'sin localstorage. But the thing is that after several minutes, those blob images got expired the URL can no longer access the image.

How can I extend blobs expiring time?